# consuming WCF services in windows Mobile Application while saving records error is coming

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

consuming WCF services in windows Mobile Application while saving records error is comingFallowing is the code i have written in MainPage.xaml.cs for inserting Records:->

```
 ServiceReference1.AdminClient client = new ServiceReference1.AdminClient();
 string Username = txtName.Text;
 string Password = txtNumber.Text;
 string Email = txtemail.Text;
client.InsertLoginAsync(Username, Password, Email);
```

Error is:->An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code